# How to get audio from GSM modem - Not to a speaker but as a RTP stream

Tags: webrtc, asterisk, gsm, rtp

I have a GSM modem with a serial port and soldered points for MIC and Speaker. Through the serial port I can send AT signalling commands, send SMS and make/receive calls. I had to solder a speaker and a MIC  to the modem card. My problem is that I want to read the audio stream as a RTP stream, possibly through some intermediate hardware/software. My goal is to ultimately get the audio as a RTP stream on some port with some RTP profile. I understand that I need to run a UDP server to serve the audio over a UDP IP-address/port tuple, but how do I get the audio to the UDP server in the first place?  Codec conversion is also something that I am familiar with and am aware that I may need it.

This is a simplified diagram of what I intend to do:

```
 GSM-modem-audio ---*1*---> audio-over UDP(ip-address:port)---->  
      >---*2*-->  Kurento RTPendpoint---*3*--->Kurento-WebRTC endpoint
```

I don't know how to handle part * 1 * piece of the puzzle.

Comment: Are you talking about getting direct access to the encoded audio stream of a PSTN phone call placed/received by the modem, or about running VOIP through a cellular packet connection?

Comment: @Sneftel Sorry for the delay in responding.  Yes, I want to get direct access to the encoded stream. I will be using Asterisk to make/receive calls from a bank of GSM modems. Sangoma provides [this module](http://wiki.sangoma.com/wanpipe-linux-asterisk-gsm).  However, that will work with a GSM PCI card and I believe that the Sangoma drivers do what I am looking for here. I want this functionality but thru the use of a GSM modem bank which only has a serial interface and  MIC&Speaker points on the board. It will be a good learning experience to connect audio  from this level to webRTC -:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way: get Rassbery-PI, get usb sound card, connect analog output of modem to sound card.
Have be no problem convert digital ALSA sound card signal to rtp stream.

More complex way - create special hardware which will do same.. oh wait! That will be like sangoma board.

Anyway it is not wise idea create something like that yourself except for educational purpose, becuase it will be costly or low quality.

Comment: "Anyway it is not wise idea create something like that yourself except for educational purpose, becuase it will be costly or low quality." Are you referring to the first part of your answer, the second "more complex way" answer or in general? Thanks

Comment: I say "china gsm gateway will be better then your home-made solution".

Comment: Sure, but development of such device will cost MORE.